# Flutter Web Selectable Text not deselecting when clicking or selecting other widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-text

I have this problem only when using Flutter Web version. 2.8 and 2.10 , when I tried using Flutter 2.5.3 and other previous version the problem doesn't happen.

Example Widget inside Column:

```
SelectableText("'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy '",)),
SizedBox(height: 20),
Divider(),
SelectableText("'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text '",)),
```

The output:

[image]

When I clicked the bottom selectable or other widget beside the selectable text it doesnt deselect the previously selected text, and also when I selected a new text on another selectable text the previous selection on the top is still highlighted which is not the behaviour I expected.

Is there some change on this widget on the newest version that I didn't notice?
Thanks

Comment: I believe it is an issue and is tracked here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78909

Comment: Have you find any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can update your SDK version of Flutter to 3.3 and use [SelectionArea class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectionArea-class.html):

> A widget that introduces an area for user selections with adaptive
> selection controls.
>
> This widget creates a SelectableRegion with platform-adaptive
> selection controls.

as described on this Medium Article: [What’s new in Flutter 3.3](https://medium.com/flutter/whats-new-in-flutter-3-3-893c7b9af1ff).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).